# Error installing VirtualBox in Ubuntu 18.04: “Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

When I tried to install VirtualBox using :

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

I got the following error stating that the following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
virtualbox : Depends: virtualbox-dkms (>= 5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
virtualbox-source (>= 5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
virtualbox-modules
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I even tried to purge and reinstall using `virtualbox-qt` and `virtualbox-5.2` but was of no use.

Comment: If Ilario Gelmetti's answer doesn't solve it, I'm wondering what your software sources are? Maybe VirtualBox is from a source that's not very compatible with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency with held broken packages error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-with-held-broken-packages-error)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you missed running an `apt update` before trying to install VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt update
```

If after this you still get the same error message, try listing held packages with

```
apt-mark showhold
```

And to “uphold” a specific virtualbox related packages with this command:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

Comment: the error got reduced to : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-qt : Depends: virtualbox (= 5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. The apt-mark showhold does not give any output.

Comment: Seems that `apt update` didn't manage to do its work.
Make sure that you have a line with:

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse`

in your /etc/apt/sources.list
You can check that with:

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`